# Mostrar subpáginas debajo de la página principal en búsquedas de Google

Tags: html, seo, google-search-console

Tengo una web y me gustaría que cuando se hace una búsqueda de ella en Google me **aparezcan las subpáginas debajo de la página principal** como se ve en esta foto.[image: Según he leído esto se llama enlaces de sitio]
Tengo el sitemap de la web indexado en Google Search Console y añadido a mi web (https://grovot.com/sitemap.xml). Según Google, el proceso de mostrar los enlaces de sitio debajo de la página principal es automático dependiendo de la importancia que ellos le den a cada una de las páginas, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de forzarlo o algo más que pueda hacer.
*He visto que había una pregunta similar a esta, pero la respuesta que daban no me ha solucionado nada. Además, es del año 2017, por lo que muy probablemente los métodos para hacer este procedimiento hayan cambiado ya.*

Comment: Hace cuanto agregaste el XML?

Comment: Pues hace una semana o incluso un poco más

Comment: Ya te doy un truco para ayudarte, el hecho que escribas este post es porque no tienes busquedas en google porque si no fuese otra historia, google es un robot, por ende aprende de lo que le dices, solo busca tu web con su nombre y dominio en la busqueda principal de google por 1 semana todos los dias unas 3 o mas veces al dia y listo, tomara tu xml mas rapido, te lo digo por experiencia

Comment: Pero la web en la última semana ha tenido 59 impresiones y 14 clicks. No son suficientes?

Comment: No eso es el minimo, creeme si puedes hacerlo, yo lo hago con mis clientes, lo mas tardado son 2 semanas y listo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lamentablemente creo que tu no puedes hacer nada para que eso ocurra, es algo que hace google algoritmicamente según la relevancia de las páginas de tu sitio web. De todas formas te dejo por aqui una página web que te da ciertos consejos para conseguir que google haga esto mas pronto que tarde.

https://www.luisrevuelto.es/sitelinks-enlaces-de-sitio-organicos/

Comment: Pues muchas gracias. Intentaré mejorar algunos aspectos de la web para ver si así me los coloca

Answer (score 0):

Eso es parte ya de Google y la forma como interpreta tu relevancia. Lo que si te recomiendo, es hacer buenas prácticas SEO On Page para darle poder a ello.

Si te da curiosidad, el término asociado a ello es: Sitelinks.